# ZF2 - Asset Manager, slowing down application

Tags: zend-framework2

I started writing this as I was struggling to get ZF2 Asset Manager to work properly however in mid swing I managed to sort out the problem and felt the question still needs to be asked in order to help others.

If you are looking for an Asset Manager for ZF2, try out: https://github.com/RWOverdijk/AssetManager

The problems I faced was essentially due to a lack of documentation and the solution was really simple.

For asset manager to work, you essentially need to generate a cache of your files that your app can locate. Once the files have been located and are reachable, your app will speed up tremendously. The first problem I faced was the module.config.php file. The documentation is not clear in how to set this up correctly.

My original file looked like this:

```
'asset_manager' => [
    'resolver_configs' => [
        'paths' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../assets',
        ]

    ],
],
```

Which essentially tells my application to look in the module/assets directory for any assets. This worked out the box but was VEERY slow...

I read up about caching and my modification of my file was as follows:

```
'asset_manager' => [
    'caching' => [
        'default' => [
            'cache'     => 'FilePath',  // Apc, FilePath, FileSystem etc.
        ],
    ],
    'resolver_configs' => [
        'paths' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../assets',
        ]

    ],
],
```

This did nothing... so after searching code in gitHub to see how others had implemented Asset Manager I discovered you can set the options of where to put the cache... so my new config became this:

```
'asset_manager' => [
    'caching' => [
        'default' => [
            'cache'     => 'FilePath',  // Apc, FilePath, FileSystem etc.
            'options' => [
               'dir'   => getcwd() . 'public',
            ]
        ],
    ],
    'resolver_configs' => [
        'paths' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../assets',
        ]

    ],
],
```

Still my app was not working although the assets where being generated in a folder called: trunkpublic in the root of my app. After much frustration I realised that I need to update:

```
'dir'   => getcwd() . 'public', to 'dir'   => getcwd() . '/public',
```

Adding a slash put the folder in the public directory, which in retrospect is obvious since the app needs access to the cached files.

My final configuration is this:

```
'asset_manager' => [
    'caching' => [
        'default' => [
            'cache'     => 'FilePath',  // Apc, FilePath, FileSystem etc.
            'options' => [
               'dir'   => getcwd() . '/public',
                //'dir'   => getcwd() . '/data/cache/assets',
            ]
        ],
    ],
    'resolver_configs' => [
        'paths' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../assets',
        ]

    ],
],
```

You will notice I have this snippet commented out:

```
//'dir'   => getcwd() . '/data/cache/assets',
```

The above is super fast and is used with the Filepath option and is great for development mode, it essentially generates a hash of the file in the /data.cache/assets directory however for a production environment I prefer to have actual files saved to the assets cache found in: public/assets as this allows the app to grab the files directly without having to invoke php.

**NOTE:**

There was another issue I faced and this is due to misleading documentation

If you look at this line:

```
'cache'     => 'Filesystem',  // Apc, FilePath, FileSystem etc.
```

You may be tempted to add your files using CamelCase... however some may reauire CamelCase and others may require Normalcase... check the code for this...

Comment: Have you tried contributing it via github? I use https://github.com/widmogrod/zf2-assetic-module, but I wished ZF2 included that sort of thing as a standard component.

Comment: This pretty much does the trick: https://github.com/RWOverdijk/AssetManager, it uses Assetic. Now that I have it working properly, what an awesome little module.

Answer (score 0):

works for me!!

```
'asset_manager' => array(        
    'caching' => array (
        'default' => array(
            'cache'     => 'FilePath',  // Apc, FilePath, FileSystem etc.
            'options' => array(
               'dir'   => './public',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'resolver_configs' => array(
        'paths' => array(
            'MyModule' => __DIR__ . '/../public',
        ),
    ),
),
```

now i try fix flter JSMin and JSSqueeze

tank you!